# Insert rating and calling average of that given rating

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

I am trying to insert rating in database and calling average of that given rating from database

```
<?PHP
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "akdnaklnd", "lfnlfns","faknfns");
$game = $_POST['game'];
$post_rating = $_POST['rating'];
$find_data = mysqli_query( "SELECT * FROM rates WHERE game='$game'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_data)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $current_rating = $row['rating'];
    $current_hits=$row['hits'];
}
$new_hits = $current_hits + 1;
$update_hits= mysqli_query("UPDATE rates SET hits = '$new_hits' WHERE id='$id'");                                  
$pre_rating= $current_rating + $post_rating;
$new_rating = $pre_rating / $new_hits;
$update_rating = mysqli_query("UPDATE rates SET rating ='$new_rating' WHERE     id='$id'");
header("location : average.php");
?>
```

Comment: Would be great if you could mention the error you are seeing as well.

Comment: running in joomla not able to access this page ?

Comment: Not able to get the output

Comment: How can we help you if you don't know what causes the error?

Comment: I had given syntax in last line that--"header("location : average.php");" , i am not able to redirect in average.php code .

Answer (score 0):

Add `$connection` param to `mysqli_query` like this:

```
$find_data = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM rates WHERE game='$game'");
```

Delete space symbol after "location" before colon: `header("location: average.php");`

Answer (score 0):

try to debug it by removing all the MySQL stuffs from code and keep redirection code with no space ie .

```
header("location:average.php");
```

if it works then there must be an error on your MySQL query. try adding error check after execution each MySQL query operations. Hope that will help you finding the breakpoint where your execution terminates before redirection statement.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need not to select data you can directly write your update query like this.
Please make sure you pass variable instead of string for better practise use double and single quotes and dott too.

**Most important pass connection variable.**

```
$update_hits= mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE rates SET hits = hits+1 WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Try echo $update_hits if it give one then query successful else there is issue.

For that you can use error log

```
    if (!$result) {
        $errorQuery = $update_hits;
        throw new Exception(mysqli_error($connection));
       $errorMessage =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$e->getMessage());
       echo $errorMessage;
       exit();
    }
    else{
       echo "Success";
    }
```